# What design pattern to make validators for textfield inputs?

Tags: swift, design-patterns

I am building the on-boarding for my app. I would like to validate the users input within textFieldDidEndEditing() in order to provide instant feedback to the user if something is wrong. Each textField needs different validation, eg one will confirm the input is a valid email, another will confirm valid date of birth.

I have tried many design patterns to make this clear flexible but none of them seem possible in swift. I was wondering if anyone has a good solution for this?

I want to avoid something bad like this:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textfield: UItextField) { 
    if textfield = emailTextBox {
        if validEmail(textfield.text) {
            textfield.shadowColor = blue
        } else {
            textfield.shadowColor = red
        }
    }
    if textfield = dateofBirthTextBox {
        if validDOB(textfield.text) {
            textfield.shadowColor = blue
        } else {
            textfield.shadowColor = red
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to get as close as possible to this:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textfield: UItextField) {
    if textfield.isValid {
       textfield.shadowColor = blue
    } else {
       textfield.shadowColor = red
    }
}
```

I have thought of/tried:

- extending UItextField with many validation functions
- extending UItextField with a generic validator function that is overwritten by a subclass and each textField is an subClass
- Validator protocol that each UItextField subclass implements
- Validator superclass then get put subclasses into a dictionary with [UItextField:Validator]

I have not been able to implement any of these well because of limitations within Swift and would appreciate any help.

Many thanks

Comment: `because of limitations within Swift` - what kind of limitations are you referring to? Swift is quite a powerful and expressive language.

Comment: main problems with swift were: 1 - you can't overwrite a methods declared in an extension. 2 - putting different subclasses as the values in a dictionary like [UITextField:Validator] required hacking of generics. 3 - can't declare a UITextField conforms to protocol when using @IBOutlet var textField:UITextfield!

Comment: there were also other reasons not to choose those patterns because of extending UItextField with many validation functions didn't reduce number of IF statements needed and also bloated out UItextField with functions that would not be needed by many implementations

Comment: I think you confuse design decisions with language limitations. #1 was recently enforced after many developers abused this "feature". #2 not sure you're referring to, but you can store subclasses of the value type in the dictionary. #3 You're misusing the protocol - the XIB generates a concrete class, use that instead.

Comment: Seems most of so called limitations are in fact constructs that prevent you to misuse the language.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a bad thing that swift restricts these actions, just the approaches I might have used in other languages do not work here. 
What would you recommend for the result i'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

One good way is try to use [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift) for this issue it provides a reactive solution technique to handle such cases and avoid the old bad one , see here is a demo that demonstrates it [RXSwiftDeno](https://www.raywenderlich.com/138547/getting-started-with-rxswift-and-rxcocoa)

in that tutorial this is the title of textfeild validation section **RxSwift and Direct Text Input**